# Почему не работает валидатор в Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular2

Есть попытка создания собственного валидатора для формы в `Angular 5` :

```
form: FormGroup; 

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    dpassword: ['', [Validators.required, this.validateMatchPasswords.bind(this)]],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
  });
}

validateMatchPasswords(control: FormControl) {
  return {
    error: this.form.get('password') === this.form.get('dpassword')
  };
}
```

Идея в том что валидатор должен проверять при регитрации, что основное поле пароля и его повторение одинаковые. Но почему-то падает ошибка что не может найти метод `get()` у объекта `this.form` и вообще `this.form` получается `undefined`, хотя я сделал `this.validateMatchPasswords.bind(this)`.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at RegistrationComponent.validateMatchPasswords (registration.component.ts:32)
    at eval (forms.js:759)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeValidators (forms.js:759)
    at FormControl.eval [as validator] (forms.js:711)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl._runValidator (forms.js:3433)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:3387)
    at new FormControl (forms.js:3905)
    at FormBuilder.control (forms.js:7899)
    at FormBuilder._createControl (forms.js:7965)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так происходит, и как это можно поправить?

Comment: Возможно это происходит потому что `validateMatchPasswords` выполнятся до того, как происходит создание формы в `ngOnInit`. Попробуйте перенести создание формы в конструктор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Валидатор вызывается до создания объекта FormGroup, поэтому и не может обратиться к property 'get' of undefined.
Задача решается так:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username: ...,
      passwords: new FormGroup({
        password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        repeatPassword: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      }, this.passwordMatchValidator),
     email: ...
    })
  }

  passwordMatchValidator(g: FormGroup) {
    return g.get('password').value === g.get('repeatPassword').value
       ? null : {'mismatch': true};
  }
```